# SQL access Group By and Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, group-by

I'm having an issue with MS Access with my SQL statement.

I have companies and teams, and they each have a balance of money.
(Company1 can have team 1,2,3,4 and Company2 can have team 1,2,3,4,5. Though Comapny1 team1 is not the same as Company2 team1!)

But I have a ton of entries which each correspond to a seller.

I want to sum every balances for each company and each team, no matter which seller it is:

I actually have :

```
    SELECT Company, Team, Sum(Balance) AS tot_balance
    FROM Retro2014
    GROUP BY Company, Team
```

But the amounts are 5 to 10 time bigger then they should be when i sum it manually. (But I have around 1200 seller, I can't do it all manually)

EDIT: What I want is something like this:

```
Company  Team  tot_balance
-------  ----  -----------
Company1 Team1 1000
Company1 Team2 1530
Company1 Team3 120
Company1 Team4 500
Company2 Team1 800
Company2 Team2 750
Company2 Team3 420
Company2 Team4 820
Company2 Team5 120
...      ...   ...
```

EDIT2:

I have those values now :

```
Company Team    tot_balance REAL_Balance
10      90      2 534.60    269.06
10      92      813.30      120.89
10      95      1 384.75    210.89
10      96      950.72      142.43
10      97      3 957.03    789.92
10      98      4 822.34    1128.71
```

EDIT3 : And the source values are those:

```
COMPANY TEAM    SELLER  BALANCE
10      50              123.65
10      90      L07630  245.06
10      90      L07630  4
10      90      L07630  8
10      90      L07630  4
10      90      L07630  8
10      92      L96420  32.93
10      92      L96420  87.96
10      95              35.74
10      95              16
10      95              4
10      95              12
10      95              12
10      95              131.15
10      96      L04771  65.5
10      96      L04771  12
10      96      L04771  8
10      96      L04771  8
10      96      L04771  48.93
10      97      L94605  61.93
10      97      L94605  4
10      97      L94605  8
10      97      L94605  233.76
10      97      L94605  344.97
10      97      L94605  90.33
10      97      L94605  38.93
10      97      L94605  4
10      97      L94605  4
10      98      L95652  42.51
10      98      L95652  34.75
10      98      L95652  549.26
10      98      L95652  320.36
10      98      L95652  20
10      98      L95652  112.58
10      98      L95652  41.25
10      98      L95652  8
```

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your query.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your data and what sum you get when calculating it manually? Your statement looks OK.

Comment: perhaps you need to group by something else as well.  like a year or a date.  The query is fine; but you're likely missing something else.  Seeing the table structure for Retro2014 may help us figure it out.

Comment: What' the 2 after 90 and before 534.60?  and 1 and 3 and 4 in other rows?

Comment: i have edited the question since it was important information

Comment: `Select * from Retro2014 where company =10 and team = 92` results in what?  813.30 to 120.89 seems way off..  I keep thinking you need to group by something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the table don't contain multiple entries on Company, Team, Balance
than you SQL should work just fine.
But given your explained issue, I pressume there are more values than what are shown and can therefore cause more rows with the same information shown more than once, which would result in an incorrect summerization. Here is what I would suggest:

```
Select Company, Team, Sum(Balance) as tot_balance from (
SELECT Company, Team, Balance
FROM Retro2014
GROUP BY Company, Team, Balance ) as b
GROUP by Company, Team
```

Comment: Wow, excellent, it did work. Could you please explain briefly how this works, it should help me from now on!

Comment: The table Retro2014 contains more than one row with the same company, team and balance.
So when you use group by the first time, it will group Company and Team. But every row that has the same value of balance will be included in the sum.
If you use group by of all three elements first, you remove the duplicate rows that causes the sum to become incorret.
Than after that you can continue with your summerization.